# Can my school look at my search history through Google Chrome if I am logged in through my school account?

Tags: account-security, google, gmail

I am doing online school at the moment and I am wondering if my school tracks and looks at everything I search just through my school Gmail account. I am on my own network and pc which has never been connected to the school network in any way except through the school Gmail account.

Comment: You've asked if they *do track and look* and there is no way anyone can answer that but them. If you are using a school-supplied account, then, yes, your activity is *logged*. what they do with that log is up to them.

Answer (score 1):

The searches are logged under your Google Account and could be seen by your school admins.  You can disable search and other activities from being logged via your Google Account's [Activity Controls](http://myaccount.google.com/activitycontrolsactivity). You can also delete previously logged activity - see Privacy & Personalization panel in your Google Account.